# How to kill all Docker containers based on a given image?

Tags: docker

How to kill all Docker containers based on a given image?

As an example:

```
sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
58251f04892a        mariadb:10.4        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   53 seconds ago      Up 52 seconds       3306/tcp                 optimistic_ramanujan
2a08ee7d9afe        mariadb:10.3        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          3306/tcp                 thirsty_taussig
65abd7a3b3e1        mariadb:10.3        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          3306/tcp                 angry_lederberg
32076aa4745e        mariadb:10.3        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          3306/tcp                 distracted_kapitsa
```

I would like to kill all containers based *directly* on the `mariadb` image (ideally, both 10.4 and 10.3).

The following solution does not work since it will kill all containers having `mariadb:10.3` as an ancestor--and not only those directly based on that image:

```
sudo docker kill $( sudo docker ps --filter ancestor=mariadb:10.3 )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do want I want: killing all containers *directly* based on `mariadb` regardless of their tag--and without killing containers having `mariadb` somewhere higher in their ancestor list.

```
sudo docker kill $(
  sudo docker ps --format '{{.ID}} {{.Image}}' | awk '$2 ~ /^mariadb:/ { print $1}'
)
```

Comment: My vote for piping grep and cut where awk is the perfect tool for the task :)

Comment: i was wondering why you did the `--format` as your awk works without it then i realised that it makes things future proof to changes in the default `docker ps` output.

Comment: Exactly @simbo1905. You can't safely rely on the default format: without an explicit format, the output of `docker ps` is not only version-dependant (I assume) but also site-specific since it can be configured system-wide using the `psFormat` configuration option (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#configuration-files).